# Expresso Store orders paid for but not appearing in order list

Tags: expresso-store

I'm having a serious, but intermittent, problem with exp-resso whereby my client is receiving payment for orders made on the site but the orders are not appearing in the 'Orders' section of the store.

For example this weekend they received payment for orders numbered 171, 172 and 173 but only 172 appears in the order list.

Obviously this is causing them a major problem as they have no idea what people have ordered.

Where can I look to investigate the cause of this? It happens reasonably frequently.

Martyn

Comment: Which version of Store and EE are you using? Does the checkout process complete and is the user redirected back to the order confirmation page upon paying for the order? Which payment gateway are you using?

Comment: Which gateway are you using? What is most likely happening is the gateway is not letting Store know about the successful payment, so Store thinks they are still a cart (you will see them in the orders list if you set the status dropdown to "Incomplete").